# How to prevent Malicious File Execution in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I currently have a asp.net site that allows users to upload files and subsequently view them using HTTP. Is there a simple way to prevent a user from uploading a malicious script/file onto my server then attempting to run that script by calling its directory via http?

Comment: Calling it's directoy via http would execute the script on the users computer. Just don't allow exes etc. Work with whitelists, not blacklists

Comment: Can't you just disallow access to the directory via IIS?  What am I missing?

Comment: @Andrew if you do this would this prevent you from uploading any file? The point is to upload only a certain type of file.

Comment: You should be able to give IIS and/or ASP.NET write access to the directory without allowing the directory to be served by HTTP.  I don't know the details off the top of my head.

Comment: @Andrew sorry I should have also specified that I do want to serve the files that I upload.

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove the ASP script mapping on that particular folder.

Read the [complete answer by Steve Schofield here](http://forums.iis.net/p/1152469/1882312.aspx#1882312).

Comment: Does this mean the server won't run any aspx html or js files?

Comment: It will not run ASPX file inside a specific folder. HTML is client side, and so is JS.

Comment: So is it still possible to get some data using JS?